# How to refresh JSON data with Tabbed Navigation using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tabs, setinterval

Having some problems trying to get a rather simple UI working properly. Thought maybe someone here could lend some advice and point me in the right direction. Here's what I've got going on.

1) Pulling in a JSON string (multidimensional array) from a PHP page using getJSON.
2) Using 2 jQuery.each statements to iterate through JSON data and display the data to the page. The first jQuery.each creates my side navigation (lists computer lab names). The second jQuery.each creates a data table with the machines, their status, and a date.

So where I'm running into a problem is I want to my side navigation to act as tabs and tab through the data table. I can get that working fine. Here is where I run into a problem.....I want my JSON data to refresh every 2 mins so I'm using setInterval to go out and get the JSON string again. This ends up breaking down my tabs/navigation. I understand why it breaks down but I'm kind of lost as far as how to fix it or an alternative way to code this.

The JSON string looks like this.....

```
{
    "Labs": [
        {
            "name": "Computer Lab 1",
            "host": [
                {
                    "name": "c1ms",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/25/11  02:05 PM"
                }
            ],
            "downcount": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "Computer Lab 2",
            "host": [
                {
                    "name": "berk1",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/26/11  08:55 AM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "berk2",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/26/11  08:50 AM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "berk3",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/26/11  08:50 AM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "berk4",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/26/11  08:55 AM"
                }
            ],
            "downcount": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "Computer Lab 3",
            "host": [
                {
                    "name": "pc1",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/26/11  08:50 AM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "pc2",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/26/11  08:55 AM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "pc3",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/30/11  12:20 AM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "pc4",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/26/11  08:50 AM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "pc5",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/26/11  08:55 AM"
                }
            ],
            "downcount": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Computer Lab 4",
            "host": [
                {
                    "name": "mac1",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/22/11  03:05 PM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "mac2",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/22/11  03:10 PM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "mac3",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/22/11  03:05 PM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "mac4",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/23/11  12:20 PM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "mac5",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/16/11  01:30 PM"
                },
                {
                    "name": "mac6",
                    "status": "up",
                    "date": "8/22/11  03:05 PM"
                }
            ],
            "downcount": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

---Code so far---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


 setInterval('$("#table").trigger("getJson")', 3000);

 $("#table").bind("getJson", function(event){
  $.getJSON('json.php', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    $("#table").trigger("drawTable", data);
  });
 })
 $("#table").bind("drawTable", function(event, json){
    //build the table, json is your jsonData from the call
    $.each(json.Service, function(i,object){
        $.each(object.host, function(e,o){
            $('#table').append("<tr><td width='30%'>"+o.name+"</td><td width='10%'><span class='status-"+o.status+"'>"+o.status+"</span></td><td width='60%'>"+o.date+"</td></tr>");
    });
    });
 });
 $(".tableRow").live("click", function(event){
   //sidenavigation code
   $.each(json.Service, function(n, nav) {
      $('#db-sidenav ul').append("<li>"+nav.name+"</li>"); 
   });
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might consider using the .live() feature of jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

this way each time your DOM elements are refreshed, the event handler will bind the navigation function that you have added.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

## fix the constant table appending

### html for table

```
<table>
  <thead>...</thead> // columns
  <tfoot>...</tfoot> //footer in front of body to help render speed
  <tbody>...</tbody> // content
</table>
<? id="db-sidenav">
  <ul>....</ul>
</?>
```

### js advice

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


     setInterval('$("#table").trigger("getJson")', 3000);

     $("#table").bind("getJson", function(event){
      $.getJSON('json.php', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $("#table").trigger("drawTable", data);
        $("#db-sidenav").trigger("updateNavigation", data);
      });
     });
     $("#db-sidenav").bind("updateNavigation", function(event, json){
        //sidenavigation code
        var sideNav = $(this);
        var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
        $.each(json.Service, function(n, nav) {
         ul.append("<li>"+nav.name+"</li>"); 
        });
        $("ul", this).fadeOut("fast", function(){
          //on animation complete
// warning, this will remove all child nodes, tweak this to remove only the UL we care about if there is more content in the side-nav than just the UL
          $(this).remove();
          ul.appendTo(sideNav);
          ul.fadeIn();
        }); 
      });        
     });
     $("#table").bind("drawTable", function(event, json){
        //build the table, json is your jsonData from the call
        var table = $(this);
        var tbody = $("<tbody></tbody>"); //appending the tr's to an un-attached element prevents DOM thrashing as we rebuild (i have no idea how big this table may get)
        $.each(json.Service, function(i,object){
            $.each(object.host, function(e,o){
               tbody.append("<tr><td width='30%'>"+o.name+"</td><td width='10%'><span class='status-"+o.status+"'>"+o.status+"</span></td><td width='60%'>"+o.date+"</td></tr>");
        });
        $("#table tbody").fadeOut("fast", function(){
          $(this).remove();
          tbody.appendTo(table);
          tbody.fadeIn(); 
        }); 
        });
     });
    });
    </script>
```

---

## Old Answer

```
<script>
$(document).ready(){


 setInterval('$("#table").trigger("getJson")', 120000);

 $("#table").bind("getJson", function(event){
  $.getJson("myUrl.php", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    $("#table").trigger("drawTable", data);
  });
 })
 $("#table").bind("drawTable", function(event, json){
    //build the table, json is your jsonData from the call
 });
 $(".tableRow").live("click", function(event){
   //sidenavigation code
 });
}
</script>
```

Comment: i built on Tom's .live()  it's a great function.  the above is just a framework for how I would start to build the solution.  let me know if you have questions.

Comment: So far I've been able to pull in the table but as it loops it appends the table over and over again as it refreshes.  I've also not been able to pull in the navigation data from the JSON for some reason.  Went ahead and edited my post with what I've got so far.

Comment: I've cleared up the constant appending, take a look.  I feel you're using the .live()  function incorrectly.  a .each() in a live() function, well, it looks like click on one ".tableRow" will append alot of side navigation bars Each Click. I'll try to take a look before lunch.

Comment: Ok yeah that seems to be working better.  Yeah the .live() confuses me a bit.

As for the navigation. I had been using jQuery/CSS with id names for the navigation that corresponded with id names for blocks of table data.  Then I was just hiding/adding/removing classes to show data. Not sure if that was the best way to do it.  This is obviously a bit more complex than anything I've done before.

Comment: heh, and now i'm playing with animations.  I think i have the idea for your sidenav redraw.  you don't need a click event, you know all your information you need after the json comes back

Comment: After moving the script to thy bottom of the page....seems to be loading all the data (nav and table) correctly.  When it runs the setInterval and refreshes the data, everything blinks.  Is there anyway to remove that slight delay in the fades and just make it invisible?

Comment: So now where/how would I make the sidenav work to hide/show only sections of the data table?  I tried something like on this tutorial [link](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tabs-w-css-jquery) but every time it refreshes added classes are lost and it breaks down.  It was the same problem I was originally having.

Comment: that sounds like a new question ;)  you will get a lot more people besides me on a new question.

Comment: Actually it really was the main part of the original question. "I want my JSON data to refresh every 2 mins so I'm using setInterval to go out and get the JSON string again. This ends up breaking down my tabs/navigation."  I had it pulling in the data, had the tabs working, but when I refreshed the JSON it broke down the tabs and table.